# How to use SQL Server to email an Excel workbook containing the results of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need to send an email that has the results of a query formatted as an Excel spreadsheet using SQL Server.

For example, every Monday, run a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table
```

Save the results in an xlsx Excel workbook and email it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices:

1. Use SSIS to create the xlsx file and email it out.
2. Send a CSV File
   as an attachment using **sp_send_dbmail**
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)
3. Write a .Net based CLR procedure to create the xlsx file - for
   example see this link where someone had issues and a solution with
   this: 
   ([Create an SQL CLR UDF with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907480/create-an-sql-clr-udf-with-c-sharp))

As it is, your question is way too broad for Stack Overflow and all of these solutions require not only a lot more input from yourself but will be subject to opinion as well.